# How to set Zoom level of generated pdf using abcpdf?

Tags: abcpdf

I am exporting my image into PDF using abcpdf. It works fine but the generated pdf default zoom level is not 100%,i.e. around 52.9%. Is there any way to set/define the default zoom level of pdf, so that when I open the pdf, the default zoom level should be 100%.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Setinfo Function](http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/source/5-abcpdf/doc/1-methods/setinfo.htm):

> To open at 200% zoom onto the current page:
>
> ```
> theDoc.SetInfo(theDoc.Root, "/OpenAction", "[ " + theDoc.Page.ToString() +" 0 R /XYZ null null 2 ]")
> ```